# Find matrix $B$ such that $B B^\top \approx A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$, I'd like to find a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, such that

$$B B^\top \approx A$$

where $\approx$ is intentionally vague and can mean anything practical like "in the least squares sense" or something similar.

Does this problem have a name and simple way of solving it?

Comment: $BB^T$ is positive semidefinite, so see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458038/positive-semidefinite-matrix-nearest-to-given-symmetric-matrix-y/3463383#3463383

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Cholesky gives a lower-triangular, n by n matrix, not an n by m matrix.

Comment: $BB^T$ is also always symmetric. Is it known that $A$ is also symmetric? Anyway, IIRC $A\mapsto (A+A^T)/2$ is an orthogonal projection w.r.t. a natural inner product, so in the least squares sense you might as well try and hit the symmetrized version $(A+A^T)/2$ instead of $A$.

Comment: Try SVD of ${ 1 \over 2}(A+A^T)$?